# Test print coming out spongy

Tags: ultimaker-cura, troubleshooting, anycubic-chiron

I acquired an Anycubic Chiron yesterday. I went through the leveling procedure and I think the level test print came out okay so I printed a 20 mm calibration cube and a benchy. Both of these came out with a sort of spongy consistency.

I have no idea what could be causing this so some advice would be appreciated.

I'm using Ultimaker Cura 4.0.0 and printing in PLA.

[image: Spongy Print]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turned out I had the wrong filament size set in Ultimaker Cura. Fixing this resolved the issue.

[image: under extruded calibration cube]

Comment: That could be an issue as well ... good call! :o)

Comment: Got the 3d printing discord channel to thank for pointing that one out to me

Comment: Just out of interest, what was the filament diameter that you were using, and what was the setting when it was coming out spongy? 1.75 and 3 respectively, or vice versa, or some other combination?

Comment: It's **always** Cura having the wrong default filament diameter or even ignoring your choice and replacing it silently...

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Unless it's the e-stepper, as happened to hundreds of people that took the plunge on an Ender 3 Pro for the Black Friday deal, and got a printer with two and a half times the stepper resolution that the printer's own firmware expected (to say nothing of Cura).

Answer (score 0):

I would lay odds on it being your filament is moisture saturated. You don't state what type of filament you're using, but to my understanding this is what happens when it is saturated. The water evaporates as it goes through the nozzle, which causes the filament to puff up, which leaves voids in your print.

The print itself looks like it came out rather well. I mean, the edges of the print are solid and everything is clearly defined. This would state to me the slicer and the printer itself are doing their jobs well. You didn't measure it (or leave any hint you did), so I'll assume the overall dimensions are good.

Try a different filament and see if you get better results.